# Facebook Login SDK Language Issue in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I have define login behavior of fbsdk to FBSDKLoginBehavior.web but the issue i am facing is that it always get open in Arabic and when I try to change language it redirects to safari instead of changing language on webview of application. Any help will be appreciated.[image]

Comment: Hi @Muhammad, Did you get any solution?

Comment: Sadly but we dont have any solution for it  yet

Comment: what's your device default language?

Answer (score 0):

Change login behavior of the FBSDKLoginManager object before making the login call.

```
let login = FBSDKLoginManager()
login.loginBehavior = .systemAccount;
```

And also upgrade to the latest Facebook SDK which is available at the following [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/componentsdks#downloadsdk), or update your pod if you are using Cocoapods. Also don't forget to uninstall the App and install again before testing.